# perforce 'workspace already exists' error while trying to create new workspace

Tags: version-control, perforce

While trying to create a new workspace in Perforce, I am getting an error "Unable to create a workspace named "ABCD". Workspace "ABCD" already exists.

```
Workspace Name: ABCD
Workspace Root: /prj/vlsi/vlsi_verify/users/amit/ABCD
Workspace mappings: 
//depot/VI_Digital/vi_convex/dev/manushar/workspace3/v1/convex/... 
//ABCD/convex/...
```

Why I am getting this error and unable to create the workspace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the workspace (aka client) "ABCD" already exists.
You can show the specification of the existing "ABCD" with:

```
p4 client -o ABCD
```

You can list all existing clients/workspaces with:

```
p4 clients
```

In order to delete an existing client/workspace (as long as it is yours), call:

```
p4 client -d <clientname>
```

However you can of course also just modify the existing "ABCD". On the commandline just call:

```
p4 client ABCD
```

Comment: If the workspace already exists with other user then also I will not be able to create the workspace with same name I think. I was not aware of that.

Comment: That's right - you cannot create a client that already exists and is owned by another user.